# How do you clear container of iterators?

Tags: c++

I have a task where I need to use provided functions with raw pointers that delete objects in list container based on some condition.

For example, I have `std::list<*A> myList` and I need to conditionally call a function `deleteA`:

```
 void deleteA(A* a)
 { 
      mylist.remove(a);
      delete a;
 }
```

I know this is horrible and needs smart pointers, but that's the task. Since I only need to remove elements of `myList` when some condition is true, I could not think of lambda that iterates through container and deletes its elements, so I solved the task as:

```
std::list<std::list<*A>::const_iterator> tempList;
auto it = myList.begin();
while (it != myList.end())
{
  if (*it -> deleteCondition())
      tempList.push_back(it);
  ++it;
}

if (tempList.size() > 0)
{
    auto tempIt = tempList.begin();
    while (tempIt != tempList.end())
    {
        deleteA(*(*tempIt));
        ++tempIt;
    }
}
```

My question is, do I need to clean up `tempList`?

Function `deleteA` has destroyed what they point to, and STL container should clean itself up, right?

Comment: Yes, a container of iterators doesn't need any manual cleanup.

Comment: `std::list<*A>` doesn't compile, so this isn't your actual code. In the future, please try to post something we can compile (see [mcve]).

Comment: Unrelated: `deleteA` is O(n). Since you already *have* the iterator in question, replace  the call to `deleteA` with `delete **tempIt; myList.erase(*tempIt)` instead. Or replace the entire thing with a nice foreach loop.

Comment: Wouldn't `std::list::remove_if` suffice here?

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need or need not clean tempList depends on the rest of your code. Please provide a minimum reproducible example.

On another note, consider using std::remove_if.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>

class A {
public:    
    A(int n) : m_value(n) {};
    bool deleteCondition() const { return m_value > 5; }
private:
    int m_value;
};

typedef A* Ap; // const A*& in lambda didn't compile for whatever reason

int main() {
    A a(2), b(4), c(6), d(8);
    std::list<*A> myList = {&a, &b, &c, &d};
    auto eraseBegin = std::remove_if(
        myList.begin(), myList.end(),
        [](const Ap& element){
            return element->deleteCondition();
        }
    );

    /* Causes double free in this example for whatever reason 
    for (auto iter = eraseBegin; iter != myList.end(); ++iter) {
        delete *iter;
    }
    */

    /* std::remove_if does not actually remove, 
     * instead reorders list and returns an iterator
     * to the beginning of removed range */
    myList.erase(eraseBegin, myList.end());

    return (int)(myList == {&a, &b});
    // Should return non-zero (true) if correct elements were removed
}
```